# Azure cosmos db data (SQL API) into Grafana

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, grafana

I am trying to connect Azure Data explorer plugin data source in grafana but we don’t have cluster setup for my azure application and I can’t provide cluster url in that plugin. I tried simple JSON plugin but it requires a http url and our Azure portal url is https.

Do we have any alternatives plugins or any other way to access Azure cosmos db data SQL API into grafana?

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Sreenivasa

Answer (score 1):

Sreeni. There is a Grafana use case for Azure and for Azure Cosmos DB but only through the Azure Monitor plug-in to view timeseries data of your Azure service. Grafana cannot be used as a client to the Azure SQL API, if I understand your question correctly.

Please see:  [Deploying Grafana for production deployments on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploying-grafana-for-production-deployments-on-azure/)